# jQuery Plugin to Update URL Hash As Text Input Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, hashtag

Is there a jQuery plugin which will update the URL hash of a page as the user types text into a text input?

I know that this is rather simple, but I am looking for a "smart" one, such as Google Instant search or [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), which doesn't update the hash on every `keyup()` event, but rather when the user has stopped typing for a given period of time or the text input blurs.

I also know I could sit down and write this plugin myself, as I have written several before, but I was hoping someone could suggest one that has already been written so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: bind a `setTimeout` to a `.keyup()` event. problem solved.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey yes, yes, I know it's simple. Just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that difficult. <strike>Untested code:</strike>

```
var hashTO;
$('#myTextField').on('keyup', function() {
    if(hashTO !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(hashTO);
    }
    hashTO = setTimeout(updateHash, 1000);
});

function updateHash() {
    var hashVal = encodeURIComponent($('#myTextField').val());
    window.location.hash = hashVal;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vent6/show/

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/vent6/

Comment: Hmm... even easier than I thought, I'll have to try that!

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey: Sometimes I feel charitable.

Comment: Just as a side note `encodeURIComponent()` is more preferable for encoding hash values

Comment: @spryno724:  You are right.  I knew to use it for query strings, but I hadn't thought through hashes.  Of course, you would want `#` encoded, so `encodeURIComponent()` is the right choice.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the debounce method of Underscore library (of lodash, for that matter)

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I was trying to be specific and stick to jQuery. No need to introduce another framework just for this.

Comment: In that case, I've used this in the past: http://www.briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/